# Split geom_point into quadrants and color by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to create a plot within R that has points that are split into four quadrants (like pic attached) and then applies a color to each quadrant based on group. My searching hasn't come up with much, so I'm not really sure where to start building this code. Ideally this would be using ggplot, but any advice is appreciated.

[image: Split point]

Comment: Please share with us some data (real or fake), a rendering of your desired result based on the data (drawn manually, if necessary), and some minimal code (e.g. code to plot the points, up to where you are stuck).

Comment: going to be difficult with `library(ggplot2)`an easier alternative is to use some combination of shape, fill-color, outline-color and alpha to construct a similar legend showing the 4 critical values.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're looking for mostly:

I'm going to use `iris` data as an example, with `Petal.Length` plotted on the `x-axis` and `Petal.Width` plotted on the `y-axis`.

First, calculate the mid-point for the `x` and `y` axes:

```
x_mid <- mean(c(max(iris$Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE), 
                min(iris$Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)))

y_mid <- mean(c(max(iris$Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE), 
                min(iris$Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Now, I'll use `dplyr` to assign each point to a quadrant with `mutate`, and then pipe that into `ggplot2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
  mutate(quadrant = case_when(Petal.Length > x_mid & Petal.Width > y_mid   ~ "Q1",
                              Petal.Length <= x_mid & Petal.Width > y_mid  ~ "Q2",
                              Petal.Length <= x_mid & Petal.Width <= y_mid ~ "Q3",
                              TRUE                                         ~ "Q4")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = quadrant)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = x_mid) + # plot vertical line
  geom_hline(yintercept = y_mid) + # plot horizontal line
  geom_point()
```

Which gives us the following:

[image: quadrant_plot]

You can play around with the `>=` or `<` signs if you would like to change how this handles values that fall directly on the quadrant lines.

Also, if you don't want the legend, just add `guides(color = FALSE)` at the end

Comment: I think OP wants the individual points split into 4 quadrants, not the points colored by which quadrant they reside within

Comment: If that really is the case, I'd recommend using `ggforce` or `scatterpie`: https://guangchuangyu.github.io/2016/12/scatterpie-for-plotting-pies-on-ggplot/

Comment: Thanks, Dave. These packages look like the most likely possible solution.